# How to scale a Flink Job that consumes a huge topic

Tags: scala, apache-flink

**The setup:**

- Flink version 1.12
- Deployment on Yarn
- Programming language: Scala

**Flink job:**

- Two input kafka topics and one output kafka topic
- Input1: is a huge topic between 300K and 500K messages per second. Each message has 600 fields.
- Input2: is a small topic about 20K messages per second once per day. Each message has 22 fields.
- The goal is to enrich Input1 with Input2 and the output is a kafka topic where every message has 100 fields from Input1 and 13 fields from Input2.
- I keep a state from input2 as MapState
- I use RichCoMapFunction to do the mapping
- This is a snippet from the code where I connect both streams:

  ```
    stream1.connect(stream2)
       .keyBy(_.getKey1,_.getKey2)
       .map(new RichCoMapFunction)
  ```
- I use setAutoWatermarkInterval = 300000
- No checkPoints or savingPoints are currently used

**Flink Configurations:**

- Number of partitions for Input1 = 120
- Number of Partitions for Input2 = 30
- Number of partitions for the output topic = 120
- Total number of Parallelism = 700
- Number of Parallelism for input1 = 120
- Number of Parallelism for input2 = 30
- Join Parallelism:700 (Number of parallelism to connect both stream. This is set as following:

  ```
    stream1.connect(stream2)
       .keyBy(_.getKey1,_.getKey2)
       .map(new RichCoMapFunction) 
       .setParallelism(700)
  ```
- jobManagerMemoryFlinkSize:4096m
- taskManagerMemoryFlinkSize:3072m
- taskManagerMemoryManagedSize:1b
- clusterEvenlySpreadOutSlots:true
- akkaThroughput:1500

**Yarn Configurations:**

- yarnSlots = 4
- yarnjobManagerMemory = 5120m
- yarntaskManagerMemory = 4096m
- Total Number of Task Slots = 700
- Number of Task Managers = 175

**Problem:**
The latency on the output topic is around 30min which is unacceptable for our use case.
I tried many other Flink configurations related to Memory allocations and vCores but it didn't help.
It would be great if you have any suggestions on how can we scale to reach higher throughput and lower latency.

**EDIT1: The RichCoMapFunction code:**

```
class Stream1WithStream2CoMapFunction extends RichCoMapFunction[Input1, Input2, Option[Output]] {

  private var input2State: MapState[Long, Input2] = _

  override def open(parameters: Configuration): Unit = {
    val ttlConfig = StateTtlConfig
      .newBuilder(org.apache.flink.api.common.time.Time.days(3))
      .setUpdateType(StateTtlConfig.UpdateType.OnCreateAndWrite)
      .setStateVisibility(StateTtlConfig.StateVisibility.NeverReturnExpired)
      .build()

    val mapStateDescriptor = new MapStateDescriptor[Long, Input2]("input2State", classOf[Long], classOf[Input2])
    mapStateDescriptor.enableTimeToLive(ttlConfig)
    input2State = getRuntimeContext.getMapState(mapStateDescriptor)
  }

  override def map1(value: Input1): Option[Output] = {
    // Create a new object of type Output (enrich input1 with fields from input2 from the state)
  }

  override def map2(value: Input2): Option[Output] = {
    // Put the value in the input2State
  }
}
```

Comment: More info please: (1) how are watermarks being used? e.g., are there any event-time timers or windows, or time-based joins? (2) what does "20K messages per second once per day" mean? (3) how is latency measured? (4) which state backend are you using? (5) what serializers are being used? (6) are you seeing backpressure?

Comment: 1) Only the config autoWatermarkInterval is set to 300000. I added the code for the RichCoMapFunction up in the description 2) It's a topic that has a batch load every day, which reaches 20k messages per second but only for a short period of time every day(~1min). 3)Time between reading a message from Input1 and the time this message is seen in the Output(We check also the consumer group lag) 4) The default state (MemoryStateBackend) and we don't have checkpoints 5) Specific record serde (AVRO). We have enableForceAvro and disableForceKryo. 6) Yes sometimes on the Input1 Consumer

Comment: Any ideas about this issue please?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a profiler (or the flame graphs added to Flink 1.13) to try to diagnose why this is running slowly. The backpressure/busy monitoring added in Flink 1.13 would also be helpful.

But my guess is that tremendous effort is going into serde. If you aren't already doing so, you should eliminate all unnecessary fields from stream1 as early as possible in the pipeline, so that the data that won't be used never has to be serialized. For a first pass, you could do this in a map operator chained to the source (at the same parallelism as the source), but a custom serializer will ultimately yield better performance.

You haven't mentioned the sink, but sinks are often a culprit in these situations. I assume it's Kafka (since you mentioned the output topic), and I'm assume you're not using Kafka transactions (since checkpointing is disabled). But how is the sink configured?

Why have you set the AutoWatermarkInterval to 300000 if your job isn't using watermarks? If you are using watermarks somewhere, this will add up to 5 minutes of latency. If you're not using watermarks, this setting is meaningless.

And why have you set `akkaThroughput: 1500`? This looks suspicious. I would experiment with resetting this to the default value (15).

Is there any other custom tuning, such as network buffering? I would call into question all non-default configuration settings (though I'm sure some are justified, like memory).

I would also set the parallelism for the whole job to a uniform value, e.g., 700. Fine-tuning individual stages of the pipeline is rarely helpful, and can be harmful.

How have you set maxParallelism? I would set it to something like 2800 or 3500 so that you have at least 4 or 5 key groups per slot.

Could it be that a few instances are doing most of the work? You can examine the metrics on the various sub-tasks of the RichCoMapFunction and look for skew. E.g., look at numRecordsInPerSecond.